# What to re-roll on weapon in order to optimize DPS?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have found this weapon:

[image: Slanderer]

Luckily, it already has a socket so I can re-roll other stats. The +damage can roll up to 1490 instead of 1347. But I can also re-roll the resource cost reduction to gain +10% damage.

Which one gives me more damage, an extra +140 or extra 10%?

Comment: Does the +damage minimum increase accordingly to 1290 at max?

Comment: This question is very specific, and IMHO it risks encouraging others along similar lines with a near-infinite variety of weapons. However, a good generalised answer could probably be given.

Comment: It depends on your other stats, if you have a ton of +% damage already, the pure raw damage increasing will be better, if you don't, well, the +% damage might help you more.

Answer (score 3):

The formula for DPS of a weapon is

`(MaxDamage+MinDamage)/2 * AttacksPerSecond * (1+Damage%/100)`

If you upgrade your +damage stat to +1290-1490, you will have an increase of 143 of both Min and Max Damage, so you end up with

`(1458+1882)/2 * 1.4 * 1 = 2338.0`.

OTOH, with +10% damage, you get

`(1315+1739)/2 * 1.4 * 1.1 = 2351.6`,

which is only slightly higher. Note that in the first case you keep the 9% less resource cost, which can translate into a bigger increase in actual DPS than the nominal 13.6 DPS.

Comment: My only concern is that getting a "perfect" +damage range bonus is way more harder than getting +10% damage at the mystic. I think with a few reroll of the damamge range you can achieve easily 2250+ damage but getting above 2300 will require more luck. Even though as you stated, you get to keep the ressource costreduction affixe. If you are only interested in the damage stat and don't want to waste money on rereoll, +10% damage might be the way to go.

Comment: @WizLiz You can't really say if it is harder or not, there are days when the rolls seem lucky and you get what you want and then there are days where you only seem to get vitality on rolls :p

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://paragoncalculator.com/damage_calculator.php) you can calculate your weapon damage pretty easy.

If you re-roll resource cost reduction to **+10% damage** your weapon DPS will be:

**2375.3**

If you re-roll **+damage** affix and keep resource cost reduction your weapon DPS will be around:

**2338.0**

(I calculated with +1290 - 1490 Damage; 1490 Damage is max and 1290 will vary so the result will vary too)

**Conclusion:**

For really max damage you should re-roll resource cost reduction to +10% damage. But if you only give up around 50 DPS you can keep 9% resource cost reduction which is nice too. I would say it depends on your skill build. If you need resource cost reduction you should keep it. If you dont need it, re-roll it to +10% damage. Personally I probably would keep resource cost reduction and re-roll +damage affix.

Comment: The discrepancy to my post is weird. I checked the code of the website you linked, and found the calculation difference. Instead of `X * (100+dmg%/100)` they use `X * 100/(100-dmg%)`, which is a bit higher, and seems wrong to me, as "+10% damage" increases DPS by 11.1% (worse for higher numbers, "20%" is 25% DPS). I don't know how the game calculates damage though.

Comment: Hmm, i can't confirm the calculation of the website. It might be wrong.

Comment: I went ahead and actually contacted the website owners, asking for a source.

Answer (score -1):

From [this quite useful guide](http://diablo3.judgehype.com/guide-bien-sequiper-diablo3-reaperofsouls/) (in French, sorry), the priority order of a weapon's stats is:

> `gem slot > main carac. > % damage OR % attack speed > defensive affixes`
>   Why the gem slot first ?  Because you CANNOT live without the 115-130 Critical Hit Damage that an [emerald gem](http://www.diablowiki.net/Emerald) will provide.